# Fitting a polynomial + exponential curve of a given form to data

Tags: statistics, regression

I have got a number of data sets of some parameter $m_x$ against an independent variable $x$. Through each of the data sets I need to best fit a curve of the form $A + Bc^x$ such that $A$, $B$ and $c$ are arbitrary parameters. How can I best do it, preferably with Excel or Mathematica?

Comment: I suggest reading this: http://vserver1.cscs.lsa.umich.edu/~crshalizi/weblog/491.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mathematica you have to import your data as table for $x$ and $y$ values.  The data can have the form 
$$\text{data}=\{\{x_1,y_1\},\{x_2,y_2\},...,\{x_n,y_n\}\}$$

You can create your model as

```
model = A+B*c^x
```

Then you can use FindFit function as

```
FindFit[data, model, {A,B,c},x]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you let y=m_x then y = A + B * C^x. Therefore, log(y-A) = log(B) + x * log(C), which is a bivariate linear regression problem, to which you can apply LSE to find the slope log(C) and the (y-A)- intercept is log(B). Then you work your way backwards to y.

Comment: This actually does not give a correct estimation, since your errors are not in log-space, and they get distorted by the transformation. You need to use something like a maximum likelihood estimation (for example see here http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/).

Comment: How would you get $A$ ?

Answer (score 1):

A sample data set was created using $\left( A, B, c \right) = \left( 1, 2, 0.5 \right)$. Random noise with magnitude $\le 0.1$ was stirred in. Here are the results:

[image: Mathematica computation]

Here is how to harvest the result:

[image: Harvest result]